# Update a table with data from a second table passing a condition from a third

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, case

I having some difficulty to update a table column based on the following conditions and scenario.

Condition Table:

```
EmpID   Consulting-A    Consulting-B    Consulting-C
A1      0               10              20
A2      50              30              0
A3      0               0               70
```

Data Table:

```
EmpID   Consulting-A    Consulting-B    Consulting-C
A1      10000           20000           30000
A2      0               35000           15000
A3      0               8000            0
```

Input Table:

```
EmpID   [Total Valid Consulting]   
A1      20000 + 30000 = 50000          
A2      0 + 35000 = 35000               
A3      0
```

At the end of the day, I want to have the `Input Table` `Total Valid Consulting` having the sum of `Data Table` when it has value greater than zero in the `Condition Table`.

For example, the `Total Valid Consulting` for `EmpId A1` is only `Consulting-B + Consulting-C` (from `Data Table`) since in the `Condition Table` the `EmpID A1` only have `Consulting-B` and `Consulting-C` value of greater than zero.

So I want to add only the columns data that has the value from the other table that are greater than zero. Is there a way to do so in SQL Server? This is for my update statement that I'm having issue to come up with.

Appreciate any help and advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` statement

```
INSERT INTO Input
    SELECT  EmpID,
            CASE WHEN C.[Consulting-A] > 0 THEN CT.[Consulting-A] ELSE 0 END +
            CASE WHEN C.[Consulting-B] > 0 THEN CT.[Consulting-B] ELSE 0 END +
            CASE WHEN C.[Consulting-C] > 0 THEN CT.[Consulting-C] ELSE 0 END AS f
    FROM Condition AS C
    INNER JOIN Data AS CT ON C.EmpID = CT.EmpID
```